# Encode JSON data into another JSON object

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string that I would like to include as a value in a larger JSON object that I am creating from an array. How can I create the larger JSON object without php escaping the string, and without having to decode the previously encoded string?

For example, if my JSON string is:

```
$encoded_already = '{"encoded_key": "encoded_value"}';
```

And I would like to include it in my array and json_encode() it:

```
$new_array = array(
    "some_other_key" => $some_value,
    "premade_data" => $encoded_already
);
$output = json_encode($new_array);
```

but I want to have the `$encoded_already` string be included as actual JSON, not just an escaped string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea: place a token as an attribute value and then use `str_replace` on it.

Works only if `$token` doesn't appear anywhere in your JSON.

```
$token = '%%%';
$output = str_replace( '"' . $token . '"', $encoded_already, json_encode( array(
    "some_other_key" => $some_value,
    "premade_data" => $token
) );
```

Comment: Added `$new_array =`. :) You might want to replace `'%%%'` with `uniqid()`.

Comment: OK, I was thinking about doing that but wasn't sure if there was a better way. That's going to be annoying with multiple strings though...

Comment: sometimes dumb answers are the smart ones